Words describe American dream lifestyle
It’s a two words term: xxxtter-xxtter, used to describe an affluent, perfect American dream type of lifestyle.
Context: everyone wants to live a xxxtter-xxxtter life, but it’s not realistic.

Where did you come across it and what is the question?

I’m voting to close this guesswork.

Cookie-cutter doesn't quite mean that and doesn't quite fit the pattern, but is often used of suburban life. You can probably find crossword solving websites that will help fill in the missing letters.

The phrase "jet-setter" connotes 'affluent' and the second word fits the form xxxtter: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jet-setter


Everyone wants to live a picture-perfect life, but it’s not
realistic.

picture-perfect (adj.)

Aesthetically ideal; completely lacking in defects or flaws.
Exquisite decoration made the setting for the wedding picture perfect.
1909 Atlanta Constitution 3 January m3/1
[OED online]


completely flawless : perfect
Made a picture-perfect landing
M-W



Our quest to curate a picture-perfect lifestyle extends to our
leisure activities and luxury possessions, too.
Grace
Jennings-Edquist; The Yes Woman (2021)


In 1960, handsome, charismatic John F. Kennedy became the youngest
person to be elected president in US history. His beautiful wife set
fashion trends of the day, and his two children, and their pets and
ponies, completed the picture-perfect American family.
Diane
Dakers; American Life and Best Sellers from The Catcher in the Rye
to The Hunger Games (2016)

